# UI_GRID Expandable Grid Change Row Colors

Tags: css, angular-ui-grid

How do I change the row colors for an expandable grid?

I am using this for the Main grid, which works great.

```
.ui-grid-row:nth-child(odd) .ui-grid-cell {
  background-color: #E3E3E3; !important;
}
.ui-grid-row:nth-child(even) .ui-grid-cell {
  background-color: #FFF; !important;
}
```

But this is not being picked up by the subgrid.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the result page? BTW `!important` is not added after the semicolon

Comment: Your correct.  I removed the !important and moved my custom css up to the top, so that it picks it up instead of using !important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this while digging around.
Fixed my issue.

```
  .expandableRow .ui-grid-row:nth-child(odd) .ui-grid-cell {
   background-color: #E3E3E3;
 }

 .expandableRow .ui-grid-row:nth-child(even) .ui-grid-cell {
   background-color: #FFF;
 }
```